# How to make a default parent object for a function call inside a certain scope like the window object?

Tags: javascript

I need a way to make the parent object for any "known" function call inside a certain scope a certain object, just like the window object, for example:
in javascript, we don't have to write window.document.querySelector we can write document.querySelector directly, I need to implement the same idea in my application but I'm unable to figure out the algorithm to make it?

my application works the following:

the programmer (I am programming a library) will pass an object inside a method called "move", the "move" method will take this object which will look like the following:

```
DOMMAP:{
A:{
onfirstload(){

    override() // I want this one to be like window.something, I want this to be automatically myLibrary.override() without forcing the user of my library to write manually myLibrary.override()

}
}
}
```

the myLibrary is class that have methods, the "override" method is one of the "known" methods:

```
class myLibrary{
override(){
//do something
}
move(DOMMAP){
//traverse the DOMMAP object... do some magic
}
}
```

I want this one to be like window.something, I want this to be automatically myLibrary.override() without forcing the user of my library to write manually myLibrary.override()

I want to make this thing (the global object from the perspective of the inner functions to be automatically set to myLibrary) inside the scope of the property "onfirstload" method.

Comment: JavaScript uses lexical scope, i.e. what values a function can access depends on its location in source code and is determined at definition time. You cannot change the scope of a function after it was defined. The only way to do this would if you did `window.override = myLibrary.override` when initializing the library, i.e. create global variables yourself. That however doesn't seem to be a great approach to me.  Why not leave it to the developer how they want to call the methods of your library?

Comment: You can try using `this` instead and using a `bind` or `apply` or `call` to change the context of the function call. This isn't the same as the requirements you're setting, but it could be clearer to explicitly limit the scope to an instance.

Comment: @Mike, yes I see... I don't know.. I am reading the "with" documentation...

Comment: @FelixKling, because this syntax is shorter and cleaner and easier to read and understand

Comment: I've added the `with` document just for the sake of answering your question directly. While it's for shorter and cleaner code, `with` introduces ambiguity which can cause mind-numbing bugs. Try reading up the other methods I suggested!

Comment: *"because this syntax is shorter and cleaner and easier to read and understand "* I disagree. I find it rather surprising when values/variables come to existence magically out of nowhere. But if I can do something like `import {override} from 'that-library';` then it's very obvious where the value comes from and that nothing happens outside my control. Not to mention that IDEs can better support that approach.

Comment: @FelixKling, after a lot of thinking and planning and searching, yes, I agree with you. thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 2):

We used to have `with` but it's [not recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with).

What I can suggest is you use `this` and `bind`. You can have the function in your object like so.

```js
{
  onfirstload(){
    this.override()
  }
}
```

Then call `bind` in your `move` method.

```js
class myLibrary{
    override(){
        //do something
    }
    move(DOMMAP){
        DOMMAP.onfirstload.bind(this)()
    }
}
```

Doing a bind changes the context of `this` to the class instance.

Comment: You can replace `.bind(this)()` with `.call(this)`.

Comment: This is an idea, but I think that it's easier for the user to write myLibrary.override() rather than this.override() because the $this may give a confusion for the user because he'll never know that I'm binding the method this context with the class until he read the source code of the library

Comment: @GirkovArpa, yes in the case of my code I would use call() directly

Comment: The clarity of your library is up to you. You can check out how different libraries do it. MatterJS uses method calls like how you're describing. `Render.run(render)`. VueJS does it the way I described it. the `mounted` method in an object passed to Vue specifies that `this` pertains to the current instance. Point is, if you document your library well enough, and it's consistent enough, clarity wont be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate .js file in which you can create the class and import its methods as a VAR type.
And then import this file in the root file. It would be available to all the files.